# Teradata CASE and COUNT syntax error

Tags: sql, count, case, teradata

Looking for how to write a CASE and COUNT query that will show total number of days on sale by item between dates 2/1/2017 - 4/19/2017.  I am receiving 'expected something between the word 'DATES' and the 'BETWEEN' keyword.

Table 1:

```
ITEM    SALE    DATES
Apple   Yes   4/19/2017
Apple   Yes   2/18/2017
Apple   Yes   1/17/2017
Apple   no    3/16/2017
Apple   no    4/17/2017
Banana  Yes   4/19/2017
Banana  Yes   2/18/2017
Banana  Yes   1/17/2017
Banana  Yes   3/16/2017
Banana  no    4/17/2017
```

What I am looking for:

```
ITEM    Total days on sale
Apple          2
Banana         3
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT
    ITEM,
    CASE WHEN SALE='YES' THEN COUNT(DATES BETWEEN '2/1/2017' AND '4/19/2017') END AS TOTAL_DAYS_ON_SALE_DAYS
FROM TABLE 1
GROUP BY 
    ITEM
ORDER BY 
    ITEM ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ITEM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SALE = 'YES' AND DATES BETWEEN DATE '2017-02-01' AND DATE '2017-04-19'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS TOTAL_DAYS_ON_SALE_DAYS
FROM TABLE 1
GROUP BY ITEM
ORDER BY ITEM ASC;
```

Comment: @dnoeth - I am assuming the THEN would be 1?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I have a larger data set than what I provided above and some items that have 0 sales days are showing a ? instead of a 0.  Is there a syntax that would show the 0 instead of ? or null?  I checked to make sure these items were truly not null...

Comment: Either `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` or `COUNT(CASE WHEN SALE = 'YES' AND DATES BETWEEN DATE '2017-02-01' AND DATE '2017-04-19'
         THEN 1 END)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just move that check on the DATES to the WHERE clause.
And sum the YES

```
SELECT
ITEM,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN SALE = 'Yes' 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS TOTAL_DAYS_ON_SALE_DAYS
FROM TABLE 1
WHERE DATES BETWEEN '2/1/2017' AND '4/19/2017'
 GROUP BY ITEM
 ORDER BY ITEM ASC
```

The problem with your query was that something like COUNT(DATES) would work, but not with a criteria like a BETWEEN or =.